# When does Java process die after shutdown hook?

Tags: java, shutdown

My problem is that my shutdown is happening too *early*, without waiting for the process to clean itself up.

However, if in my shutdown Thread I add a `while(true) Thread.sleep(1000);`, the process cleans up fine, and obviously, never shuts down.

This is confusing to me since the shutdown completes before many non-daemon threads are complete. For example, if I write a very simple test program in which the `main()` infinite-loops and the shutdown thread doesn't, `main` will be terminated anyway (without any exception trace coming from catching `InterruptedException`s).

So as far as I can tell the shutdown happens when the shutdown thread `run` method completes.  I think from this knowledge I can fix this by ending it in a poll loop, polling for a `Future` that denotes successful shutdown of the rest of my processes. But this seems wrong - I really just want to wait for all non-daemon threads to shutdown, and I certainly don't want to do a poll.

1. Am I correct that shutdown completes when shutdown hook's thread's `run` method completes?
2. What is a good practice way to perform the shutdown, waiting for my actual shutdown tasks to complete?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, a Java process can stop after all non-daemon threads have terminated. This is usually the time when the VM will invoke the shutdown hooks.

The hooks will be called early (i.e. with some non-daemon threads still around) if you kill the process or call `System.exit()`

If I understand you correctly, you try to do something after all other non-daemon threads have finished (i.e. wait for all other shutdown threads to complete).

This isn't easy to achieve. What you can try is to get access to the root `ThreadGroup` (it has no parent, use `Thread.currentThread().getGroup()` and then move up the chain). All threads are children of this group (or a subgroup of it).

So you can iterate over this tree until only daemon-threads are left:

```
int maxWait = 100;
while(countNonDaemonThreads() > 0 && --maxWait > 0) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
}
```

This should work, but I haven't tested it. Note that you need to be careful with code in the shutdown thread; it must not block and you must somehow handle all the errors or the VM might be unable to terminate properly.

**EDIT** The code in The code in `java.lang.Shutdown` is single-threaded, so if one of the shutdown hooks blocks, the whole VM hangs.

Now to your questions:

1. The VM terminates when `halt()` is being called. That's the last thing that `Terminate.run()` does, so yes, the VM *should* really terminate at the end of `run()`. I don't even think `run()` will ever return. There might be bugs and native code which can get in the way but that's how it's supposed to be.
2. A good practice is to use thread pools to do your work and wait for them to finish. Shutdown hooks are kind of a last resort. Since you can't really influence order and you can't be sure whether non-daemon threads might be still around, they are brittle for "last turns lights off" kind of work.

   Using thread pools, you can have several independent of them, you can cleanly define how to shut the pools down and how to wait for them to finish. And most importantly, you can build your threads in such a way that you can abort them. When you're in a shutdown hook and one non-daemon thread refuses to die, what are you going to do? With a thread pool, you'll know the kind of thread which could be inside and by that the risk to simply terminate it.

Comment: Why must it not block?  I was about to try using blocking to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I correct that shutdown completes when shutdown hook's thread's run method completes?
>   What is a good practice way to perform the shutdown, waiting for my actual shutdown tasks to complete?

Make your shutdown thread non-daemons

If this is not enough you have a bug in your code.  You can prove to yourself that a shut down hook which doesn't exit won't be killed of early.

Comment: The *shutdown thread* exits cleanly; it just kicks off a lot of asynchronous (future-driven) work that I would also like to wait for. But our promises are asynchronous and non-blocking. It sounds like a blocking wait would do the trick.

Comment: You need to make the asynchronous stuff in non-daemon threads, or have at least one non-daemon thread which waits until all the future/asynchronous stuff has completed.  Note: if these thread were running before the System.exit() they will have been killed off and would need to be restarted for the benefit of the shutdown hooks.  Your libraries may not handle this too well.

Comment: It's shutting down while I still have non-daemon thread pools running.

Comment: System.exit waits for the shutdown thread to finish - not other non-daemon threads in my application, is that right?

Comment: The process waits for the last non-daemon thread to finish. System.exit() doesn't wait for anything as such.

Comment: When is System.exit called?  Shutdown.exit seems to be called from a SIGINT from looking at Terminator.java:52. And that finishes by calling halt, then native halt0, which I'm guessing does exactly that. So it looks like the shutdown hook must block or spin, but Aaron's answer says don't block (I've asked why).

Comment: I suspect the reason is that you risk the process never shutting down and thus preventing the OS from logging off gracefully etc.

Comment: @djechlin: Your hooks must not block. The code in `java.lang.Shutdown` is single-threaded, so if one of the shutdown hooks blocks, the whole VM hangs.